# Convert generic getter expression to object getter expression

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I have a expression getter like that:

```
var expression = () => SomeInstance.Nr;
```

It is passed into a method:

```
public void AddExpression<T>(Expression<Func<T>> func)
```

Now I would like to convert that generic expression to

```
Expression<Func<object>>
```

I'm not quite sure if I can even do that. I tried something like this:

```
var converted = Expression.Convert(func, typeof(object));
var objectExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(Expression.Call(converted.Method), func.Parameters);
```

But when I call

```
var number = objectExpression.Compile()();
```

It won't return the property value.

The code can be tested here:
http://volatileread.com/utilitylibrary/snippetcompiler?id=25062

**Update:**
It seems that the invoke is wrapped a second time:

```
var converted = Expression.Convert(func, typeof(object));
var objectExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(Expression.Call(converted.Method), func.Parameters);
var anotherDelegate = objectExpression.Compile().Invoke(); // would have expected the value here
var value = ((Delegate)anotherDelegate).DynamicInvoke(); // this now does return the value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `Expression.Call` on delegates - that's only there to call methods. Instead, you want to use `Expression.Invoke`, which is specifically there to invoke delegates. Also, the key to doing expression trees is *wrapping* - invoke the inner delegate, convert the result, and wrap this in a lambda:

```
Expression<Func<int>> inputExpression = () => 42;

var newLambda = 
    Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>
    (
        Expression.Convert
        (
            Expression.Invoke(inputExpression), 
            typeof(object)
        )
    );

Console.WriteLine(newLambda.Compile()()); // Prints 42.
```

`newLambda`  is `Expression<Func<object>>` and invoking it gives you `42`, as you'd expect.

And of course, this makes it rather easy to make this an extension method (although you probably want to use templates to generate all the different `Func<...>` overloads if you need them).

Do note that this is only going to work if whatever LINQ provider you're using actually *supports* `Invoke` - in this case, it's not a problem because the lambda compiler can handle it, but if you need to use something like this with e.g. EntityFramework, you'll need to take a slightly different approach - you'll need to *unwrap* the inner lambda, convert the body of the inner lambda, and then wrap it again in another lambda. For a parameter-less expression, this is rather easy:

```
Expression<Func<int>> inputExpression = () => 42;

var newLambda = 
  Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>
  (
    Expression.Convert(inputExpression.Body, typeof(object))
  );

Console.WriteLine(newLambda.Compile()()); // Prints 42.
```

Also, for completeness, note that this only works if the inner expression is really a constant expression, and not a quote - but if you needed quoted nested expressions, you probably wouldn't be asking this question :D

Comment: I do not have `Dump` available is this in .net 4.5? (I'm working on 4.0)

Comment: @derape That's just LINQPad helper method - it's like a superpowered `Console.WriteLine` :)

Comment: One remark though: It seems that I loose the meta information about the target lambda: `inputExpression.Body.Member` has information about the target property, `newLambda` does not. Is that due to the conversion?

Comment: @derape You need to go one level deeper - there's the added `Convert` expression. You'll need to do something like `((UnaryExpression)newLambda.Body).Operand` to get to the "original" body.